# How change default selected value for "radioButtons" UI element in R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

I have R Shiny app with the "radioButtons" element and default selected value is "1".

```
radioButtons("rbtn_metrics", "Metric", 
   choices = list("Metric_1" = 1, "Metric_2" = 2, "Metric_3" = 3),
   selected = 1)
```

Let say user selected the second element (2) and see data for "Metric_2". Then he makes other selections, UI is updated, and radioButtons element set by default to "1".

How to keep the second element (2) as a default selected value in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the "UI is updated"? You are using `renderUI`?

Comment: Yes, UI is updated by using renderUI in many other places

Comment: Then it's not clear and you should post the full code (or rather a minimal reproducible code).

Comment: You don't have to post the 12K lines, only a minimal app that reproduces the issue. Then we could help.